# Stubbing stripe subscription error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I'm trying to test my payment process and I'm stuck with the problem of stubbing the subscription, this is the error message I get :

```
Double "Stripe::Customer" received unexpected message :[] with ("subscription")
```

This is the relevant part of the code for stubbing subscription :

```
@subscription = double('Stripe::Subscription')
@subscription.stub(:id) { 1234 }
@customer.stub(:subscription) { [@subscription] }
```

When I try the payment with the test card and it works, but I want to have an automated test in place in case something changes which could impact the payments

**Edit :**

per mcfinnigan suggestion I changed he last bit of code to :

```
@customer.stub(:[]).with(:subscription).and_return { [@subscription] }
```

And now I get this error :

```
Double "Stripe::Customer" received :[] with unexpected arguments
  expected: (:subscription)
       got: ("subscription")
 Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not stubbing the right thing - your error indicates that something is attempting to call the method `[]` (i.e. array or hash dereferencing) on your double `@customer`.

Check your code and see whether you are sending a `[]` to a customer object anywhere.

Are you positive the last line should not be

```
@customer.stub(:[]).with(:subscription).and_return { [@subscription] }
```

instead?

Comment: thanks for your response, can you please take a look at my update

Comment: @London ok, so you're receiving a string argument instead of a symbol.  Change the stub to `@customer.stub(:[]).with("subscription").and_return { [ @subscription] }`